# Having trouble with multiple figures on pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am currently going through the Kaggle Titanic Machine Learning thing and using http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/donnemartin/data-science-ipython-notebooks/blob/master/kaggle/titanic.ipynb to figure it out as I am a relative beginner to Python. I thought I understood what the first few steps were doing and I am trying to recreate an earlier step by making a figure with multiple plots on it. I can't seem to get the plots to actually show up.

Here is my code:

```
`
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

train=pd.read_csv("train.csv")

#Set the global default size of matplotlib figures
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(10, 5))

#Size of matplotlib figures that contain subplots
figsize_with_subplots = (10, 10)

# Size of matplotlib histogram bins
bin_size = 10
females_df = train[train['Sex']== 'female']
print("females_df", females_df)
females_xt = pd.crosstab(females_df['Pclass'],train['Survived'])
females_xt_pct = females_xt.div(females_xt.sum(1).astype(float), axis = 0)

males = train[train['Sex'] == 'male']
males_xt = pd.crosstab(males['Pclass'], train['Survived'])
males_xt_pct= males_xt.div(males_xt.sum(1).astype(float), axis = 0)


plt.figure(5)
plt.subplot(221)
females_xt_pct.plot(kind='bar', title='Female Survival Rate by Pclass')
plt.xlabel('Passenger Class')
plt.ylabel('Survival Rate')

plt.subplot(222)

males_xt_pct.plot(kind='bar', title= 'Male Survival Rate by Pclass')
plt.xlabel('Passenger Class')
plt.ylabel('Survival Rate')
`
```

And this is displaying two blank plots separately (one in the 221 location, and then next plot on a new figure in the 222 location) and then another plot with males that actually works at the end. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: I added the code to show it is a dataframe I am manipulating. Is this minimal, complete, and verifiable? The data I used is on the Titanic Kaggle competition page. Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow and actually asking a question. @DavidG

Comment: You should either create a set of 'fake' data that reproduces the problem or copy a part of the csv file here so we can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot the pandas plot to apreviously created subplot, you may use the `ax` argument of the pandas plotting function.

```
ax=plt.subplot(..)
df.plot(..., ax=ax)
```

So in this case the code may look like

```
plt.figure(5)
ax=plt.subplot(221)
females_xt_pct.plot(kind='bar', title='Female Survival Rate by Pclass',ax=ax)

ax2=plt.subplot(222)
males_xt_pct.plot(kind='bar', title= 'Male Survival Rate by Pclass',ax=ax2)
```

[image]